# Creating an Esri shapefile in C# using GDAL with Chinese field names seems to be unavailable?

Tags: c#, gdal, shapefile

I tried to create a shapefile using the GDAL library in C#. I set the shapefile character encoding to CP936 (a Chinese character encoding), but when I tried to set the field name, I encountered the following exception.`Failed to create field name '名字': cannot convert to CP936`
this is my code:

```
private static void CreateShapeFile(string path, string shapeFileName)
{
    // Register Ogr
    GdalConfiguration.ConfigureOgr();
    // Register Gdal
    GdalConfiguration.ConfigureGdal();

    string pszDriverName = "ESRI Shapefile";
    OSGeo.GDAL.Gdal.SetConfigOption("GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8", "Yes");
    //OSGeo.GDAL.Gdal.SetConfigOption("SHAPE_ENCODING", "");
    OSGeo.GDAL.Gdal.SetConfigOption("SHAPE_ENCODING", "CP936");

    OSGeo.OGR.Driver poDriver = OSGeo.OGR.Ogr.GetDriverByName(pszDriverName);
    if (poDriver == null)
        Console.WriteLine("Driver Error");

    //Create DataSource
    OSGeo.OGR.DataSource poDS;
    poDS = poDriver.CreateDataSource(path + "\\" + shapeFileName + ".shp", null);
    if (poDS == null)
        Console.WriteLine("DataSource Creation Error");

    //Create Layer
    OSGeo.OGR.Layer poLayer;
    string[] options = {"ENCODING=CP936"};
    poLayer = poDS.CreateLayer(shapeFileName, null, OSGeo.OGR.wkbGeometryType.wkbPoint, options);
    if (poLayer == null)
        Console.WriteLine("Layer Creation Failed");

    //Create attribute columns
    OSGeo.OGR.FieldDefn Field1 = new OSGeo.OGR.FieldDefn("名字", OSGeo.OGR.FieldType.OFTString);
    Field1.SetWidth(16);
    OSGeo.OGR.FieldDefn Field2 = new OSGeo.OGR.FieldDefn("Address", OSGeo.OGR.FieldType.OFTString);
    Field2.SetWidth(80);
    OSGeo.OGR.FieldDefn Field3 = new OSGeo.OGR.FieldDefn("Lon", OSGeo.OGR.FieldType.OFTString);
    Field3.SetWidth(20);
    OSGeo.OGR.FieldDefn Field4 = new OSGeo.OGR.FieldDefn("Lat", OSGeo.OGR.FieldType.OFTString);
    Field4.SetWidth(20);
    OSGeo.OGR.FieldDefn Field5 = new OSGeo.OGR.FieldDefn("UID", OSGeo.OGR.FieldType.OFTString);
    Field5.SetWidth(50);
    OSGeo.OGR.FieldDefn Field6 = new OSGeo.OGR.FieldDefn("Tag", OSGeo.OGR.FieldType.OFTString);
    Field5.SetWidth(50);

    poLayer.CreateField(Field1, 0);
    poLayer.CreateField(Field2, 1);
    poLayer.CreateField(Field3, 2);
    poLayer.CreateField(Field4, 3);
    poLayer.CreateField(Field5, 4);
    poLayer.CreateField(Field6, 5);

    //Create Feature and Point
    OSGeo.OGR.Feature poFeature = new Feature(poLayer.GetLayerDefn());
    OSGeo.OGR.Geometry pt = new Geometry(OSGeo.OGR.wkbGeometryType.wkbPoint);

    double x = 0;
    double y = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++)
    {
        poFeature.SetField(0, "你好,GDAL");
        poFeature.SetField(1, "TestProperties");
        poFeature.SetField(2, "这是一个测试");
        poFeature.SetField(3, "TestProperties");
        poFeature.SetField(4, "TestProperties");
        poFeature.SetField(5, "TestProperties");

        y = y + 30;
        pt.AddPoint(x, y, 0);

        poFeature.SetGeometry(pt);
        
        poLayer.CreateFeature(poFeature);
    }

    poFeature.Dispose();
    poDS.Dispose();
    Console.WriteLine("Mission Completed");
}
```

I tried to modify
`OSGeo.GDAL.Gdal.SetConfigOption("SHAPE_ENCODING", "CP936")`
to
`OSGeo.GDAL.Gdal.SetConfigOption("SHAPE_ENCODING", "UTF-8")`
, When the shape file is opened in ArcGIS Pro, the Chinese field names cannot be displayed normally, but the others are displayed normally.

[image: ArcGIS Pro Screenshot]

what should I do to make the Chinese field names display correctly?
Thanks in advance!